# How do I schedule an update for a wordpress page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to schedule an update to a Wordpress page. Some banner images and other content need to be changed at midnight without someone being up a midnight to press the update button. This is what I have tried:

1. Change an image on the page.
2. In the "Publish" module, click "edit" next to the "Published on" section.
3. Change the date to a future date and click OK.
4. The "Publish" button now reads "Schedule".
5. Click "Schedule".
6. The status changes from "Published" to "Scheduled".

Everything seems to work just as I would expect. The problem is that the changes made go into effect immediately on the site. I want the changes to wait until the future date I had scheduled. Does someone know why it is doing this?

Answer (score 6):

That is how the scheduling of WordPress works as of now. You need a plugin like http://wordpress.org/plugins/revisionary/ in order to schedule updates.

Comment: Revisionary is now called PublishPress Revisions.

Answer (score 2):

Today the previous plugin seems not to work and outdated. This other plugin can do the job well:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/tao-schedule-update/

Comment: This is no longer accurate.  Revisionary is currently up-to-date (April 23, 2021), but tao-schedule-update hasn't been updated in 3 years.